# Rendering a web page in Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've been looking around for a while on this but so far haven't found a working solution. Maybe I'm just not going about it correctly.

I'm looking to render a web page in Cordova. The reason for this is that the page I need requires logins and access to a database, which I can't really get easily, if at all without rendering the page.

I have tried InAppBrowser, but everytime I try that it just opens a separate window. I've also tried Ajax, but that didn't work at all, I think because it was being requested from a separate host.

What I'm looking to do is to render the exact page, from a url, in Cordova, without a browser bar, without anything else really other than the HTML from the webpage. Any help with this is VERY much appreciated.

Comment: Your Cordova app _is_ a webpage (albeit one that's hosted locally on the device).  Have you tried just throwing up an `iframe` that points at the desired external resource?  That's the typical HTML way of embedding one webpage within another.

Comment: The page you need requires login/access, but you need login/access to render the page?? This is some chicken and egg stuff, i don't quite understand. Also, InAppBrowser is able to open within the app with a back button.

Comment: Sorry let me be clearer - I'm looking to render a single html page which is behind a login

Comment: Also, I have not tried an iframe; I will try that now

Comment: also downvotes? care to explain?

Comment: maybe... you can't access data on iframes. You can try to find some "HTML5 Browser Client"... in java we use this to open a page (without a display), populate fields and simulate a click on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get this to work was through an iframe; not sure why this question was ever downvoted, it seems to me a perfectly legitimate problem which was not well answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since Cordova is just loading your own pages locally, one way is to use javascript to change/load the page you want, like so:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
</script>
```

I didn't understand your question exactly, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think you did understand the question well. I have tried something like this, but it didn't seem to work for some reason. I'll give it another try.